# Error installing Google Chrome in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu

I try to install google chrome on ubuntu 64 bit. Now i'm getting error while installing it. Errors while installing it with ubuntu software centre with google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.

Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libi/libindicator/libindicator7_12.10.2+14.04.20140402-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/liba/libappindicator/libappindicator1_12.10.1+13.10.20130920-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'